# opengl - How to draw square pixel with GL_POINTS

Tags: opengl

I try to use the following code to draw a square-shaped pixel with opengl

```
glPointSize(5.0f);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

However, the final result is a circle-shaped pixel.

Please take a look the reference http://risknfun.com/compform/w1.html
See the "Problem 4. A Grid". On the right side, the display image has square-shaped pixel.

Comment: What is your setting of glPointSmooth?

Comment: I use default values -- thank you

Comment: It works now for me. Just use glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's partly up to the OpenGL implementation (i.e., it can vary with your graphics driver), but with a bit of luck, you can turn this on or off with `glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);` or `glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);` With point smoothing turned on, you'll normally get round points, but with it turned off you'll get square points.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try to tell OpenGL not to spend time making `GL_POINTS` nice and round by calling:

```
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
```

But keep in mind that's just an hint. The OpenGL driver has ultimately the last word.